# SMART failure predicted on Harddisk after ubuntu installation on my laptop

Tags: 11.04, smart

SMART failure predicted on Harddisk after ubuntu installation 11.04 desktop version.
Press F1 to continue.

I installed ubuntu .Restarted my PC.NOw it is saying above error on boot.
Whats more worse is F1 key is not working.So my PC is dead now,i am not able to do anything.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: i have run Disk Utility in ubuntu 10.10 and the results were good.

After that i  tried installing vista,from a factory recoverable CD given along with the laptop while purchased.

I installed ubuntu 11.04 after that.Now i am getting SMART failure.

PLEase help.I am not able to proceed.Even my keyboard F1 key is not working to proceed with.

Comment: Looks like a bug if you didn't get the error message in Maverick.

Comment: Or it is just it was about to happen... and it happened right after -or during- installation (which would not mean it's Natty to blame)... I'd check the drive in another computer, to see if, indeed, SMART status is that bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
'I installed ubuntu 11.04 after that.Now i am getting SMART failure'
```

Are you in ubuntu or you can not install any os? If you do not have any OS and can not install ubuntu then try to install windows with full partition (just for hard disk check). If windows shows the same error or can not install then try partition magic boot-able CD and try to low format(delete all partition) your hard disk and just create one partition. Now try ubuntu.

If you can boot ubuntu but showing SMART error then open disk utility. Check all the Drives one by one. Find out the defected drive. Low format the drive using dd command (see on internet).After that if ubuntu show SMART error then sorry for your laptop hard disk. It is really dying. Be ready to buy a new one.

Comment: @user17118 I am not able to proceed further because my keyboard is not recognized now.

Comment: the problem is that it is not booting.Keyboard not working after the error.

Comment: i cannot enter to bios to change the boot from device option also.How can i select boot from USB if keyboard is not recognizable?

Comment: i think you mean your computer hang on welcome screen (motherboard screen). Now your hard disk is dead. unplug your hard disk and try to boot from usb.